# Encabezados se desalinean con Scroll DATATABLE

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Buen dia, tengo un menu del lado izquiero que al momento de abrirlo despliega unos submenu y la pantalla se corre... pero en el area donde tengo mi vista, cuando tengo activado el scroll se corren los encabezados... en la tabla de arriba html le tengo width: 100%

```
responsive: false,
ordering: true,
scrollCollapse: true,
scrollY: 530,
scrollX: true,
autoWidth:false,
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE
Tabla HTML:

```
<div class="card-body tabla">
                <table id="tabla" class="display cell-border" style="width: 100%; font-size: 12px;cursor:pointer">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Numero</th>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Proveedor</th>
                            <th>NIT</th>
                            <th>Pago</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

```
tbody (Estoy usando Ajax para llenar la tabla) UPDATE
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si no te falta cerrar una etiqueta o si no tienes mas `th` que `td` o viceversa, también si puedes postear el código HTML

Comment: Claro ahorita posteo ... LISTO

Comment: Claro ahorita posteo ... LISTO lo que sucede es que cuando abro mi menu lateral se corre el area donde esta mi contenido de la pag pero cuando tengo activado el scroll se corren los encabezados y cuanto lo quito ahi ningun problema se corre acomoda todo perfectamente... he encontrado varias soluciones ejemplo setTimeOut para cargar antes de entrar a la pagina que se acomoden los encabezados pero existira algun otro metodp?

Comment: verificaste que la cantidad de columnas de la cabecera es igual a la del cuerpo?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev actualice mi respuesta

Comment: @Cris223511.dev la tengo justo debajo de productoTotal en esos 3 puntos...